# Whats is the meaning of this error 500

Tags: 500-internal-error

I have the following error:

> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

And not as repair it. I changed a few files with the header and footer and then this error appearing

Comment: Can you undo your changes? Do you have original copies that you can upload via FTP?

Comment: Post your server logs

Comment: @TheDeadMedic undid the changes but still the mistake follow

Comment: Backup your `.htaccess` in the root of your WordPress installation, then delete it. If it fixes things, log into WordPress and re-save your permalink settings. If the directory is not writable, WordPress will instruct you what to put in the `.htaccess` file and re-upload.

Comment: when a try to enter on wp-admin this (500) error appear

Comment: Open your `wp-config.php` and change `WP_DEBUG` from `false` to `true`. You will see exactly which error.

Comment: thanks! 
I did and said : Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 41943040 bytes exhausted and then add the follow line on the wp-config:define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');

Comment: Either an infinite loop or some part of your script is using too much memory.

Answer (score 0):

> I changed a few files with the header and footer and then this error
>   appearing...

Bad character encoding is a very typical cause of 500 server errors.

What text editor did you use to edit the files? Are you using the correct text encoding in the files, i.e. Unicode for a linux server?

If the text encoding is OK and you're still getting the out of memory error, and that line `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');` doesn't help, ask your webhost; they will need to increase memory for you.